# Kotlin reified type parameter doesn't smart cast

Tags: generics, inline, kotlin, reification

I was experimenting with setting *uninitialized* values and was trying to get the following to work. This is mostly a curiosity in the power (and limitations) of reified generics.

I was attempting to provide default values for optional parameters of data classes.

```
inline fun <reified T> uninitialized(): T = when (T::class) {
  Long::class -> -1L // Type mismatch. Required: T  Found: Long
  String::class -> "" // Type mismatch. Required: T  Found: String
  // and so on...
  else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("No uninitialized value defined for " + T::class)
}

data class Thing(
    var id: Long = uninitialized(),
    var name: String = uninitialized() // and so on...
)
```

When `when` includes `is Type` clauses, Kotlin has *smart casting*. In this example, smart casting isn't kicking in so this will not compile.

Any ideas to accomplish something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A smart cast is applied to a specific object after you use `is` to check its type or compare it with `null`. In your example, there is no specific object for which you check the type, and nothing to apply the smart cast to.

However, you can apply manual casts to `T`, which will work as expected. Here's a working version of your sample function, updated to handle the peculiarities of Kotlin's reflection library which will be fixed in 1.1:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> uninitialized(): T = when (T::class.java) {
  Long::class.javaPrimitiveType, Long::class.javaObjectType -> -1L as T      
  String::class.java -> "" as T
  // and so on...
  else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("No uninitialized value defined for " + T::class)
}

data class Thing(
    var id: Long = uninitialized(),
    var name: String = uninitialized() // and so on...
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val t = Thing()
    println(t.id)
}
```

Comment: `as T` can be applied to the whole `when` at the very end of `uninitialized `